# The writing style of "... do not only..., ... also..."

Tags: writing-style

I don't really understand the writing style of the following sentence. Please explain it to me. Thanks.

> I do not only love my mom, I also love my dad.

Comment: I dont think the statement is grammatically correct. It should be i dont only love my mom, but i also love my dad. The pair of not only is but also.

Comment: I think it's more common to write _Not only do I X, I also Y_.

Comment: What do you mean by "style"? Do you not understand what it means, or how the grammar works?

Answer (score 0):

Your mom is not the only person you love; you also love your dad.

What exactly do you mean by writing style?

Comment: I mean "Is it a negative sentence or not only... but also pettern?".

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: I'd like to know the use of "do" in the sentence.Is it OK, RoseofWords?

Comment: It makes the sentence sound awkward. I don't know if I'd say it's _wrong_ grammatically, but it should definitely be avoided. This is in general a very strange sentence, and since I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to say I can't currently offer any revisions.

Answer (score 0):

(@RoseofWords has explained what the writer probably meant.)

*Only* can be problematic with respect to scope.

People put *only* pretty much anywhere in a sentence, and they still generally make themselves understood. Sometimes they need to add more information or context to clarify things.

In this case, the sentence would be clearer if *only* were placed closer to *my mom* and farther from *love*, to show that it qualifies the former and not the latter:

- *I do not love only my mom; I also love my dad.*

Or even clearer (since *also love* can mean love and also have other feelings for):

- *I do not love only my mom; I love my dad also.*

(Or *too* or *as well*.)  In other words, move *only* near *my mom*, and move *also* near *my dad*.

Comment: 'Generally making yourself understood' is not always sufficient. *I love not only my dad..., * and *Not only do I love my dad...* have subtly different meanings. It is difficult to tell which is intended here.

Comment: @TimLymington: That's what I said. Even though people often put *only* in  spots that introduce the possibility of other interpretations from what is intended, they generally end up making themselves understood in spite of this, by adding emphasis or additional information or context. Much of verbal communication is imprecise or, when taken out of context, says things we do not really mean. Much of verbal communication serves to clarify things we've said that might be misleading.

Comment: @TimLymington: It's like course corrections during a space flight, where  both the initial trajectory and the individual course corrections are often quite inaccurate. But with the help of our interlocutors echoing interpretations we did not intend, we somehow usually get where we wanted to go in the end. Overall, a process of successive approximation, but sometimes with wild detours - we do not necessarily get closer at each iteration (course correction).